# WiFi stops working spontaneously on my Lenovo Y50-70

Tags: networking, wireless, dual-boot

I'm having a problem connecting to the internet..

I installed **ubuntu 14.04** on my Lenovo Y50-70, dual boot with the pre-installed Windows 8 OS I had. I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) guide. Everything works perfectly, except for when I connect to WiFi networks on my Ubuntu. It seems to work well for some time (the best I got was a few minutes..), and then disconnects. After it disconnects for the first time, It won't connect again (to any WiFi network) until after I restart the computer.

If, however, I try to connect using an ethernet cable, everything goes down smoothly (no surprise-disconnects). I'd also like to point out that I **don't** get the same problem on my Windows OS.

I tried following several guides, none worked. Some technical things:

- WiFi is enabled.
- `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` won't work.
- `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off; sudo iwconfig wlan0 power on` won't work.
- restarting network manager doesn't help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide detail to help us help you. "doesn't work" doesn't help. any error messages you got may help. You may find this useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: For example adding the ouput of the commands iwconfig and ifconfig would help us and also the contents of your /etc/networking/interfaces file provides some potential crucial information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks ElderGeek and wie5Ooma.

I started following the guide ElderGeek posted, and while doing so I came across [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170012/rtl8723be-realtek-wifi-card-driver-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04/170035#170035?newreg=3f09250495b247c890fd3a824c576aa3) thread, which offered a very good answer.

The problem was the driver, apparently there is a known problem with Realtek drivers on ubuntu. Insalling the driver from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) (as proposed in the thread mentioned above) seemed to work like a charm.

I'll let you know if there's any change.

Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for the notification @bummi, I'll edit the answer